# Angular radio button scope and its values

Tags: angularjs, scope, radio-button

Currently have this on my site, but its not working correctly:

[image]

The idea is when you select the buttons (radio buttons), the title above the buttons changes to the corresponding values. For example it should be like this:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="modifier in modifiers" ng-if="modifier.type.value === 'Single' && modifier.title === 'Metal Colour'">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 main-label">
            <span>{{ modifier.title }}:</span>
            <span class="result">{{ title }}</span> 
            <span class="price">({{ price }})</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="variation in modifier.variations" >
                    <input type="radio" id="{{ variation.id }}" value="{{ variation.id }}" name="{{ modifier.id }}" ng-model="metalColour" ng-mod="{{ modifier.id }}" ng-title="{{ variation.title }}" ng-price="{{ variation.mod_price }}" class="singles" ng-checked="$index === 0" ng-click="isSelected($event)" ng-init="triggerClick()" />
                    <label class="radio colour" ng-class="variation.title === 'Yellow Gold' || variation.title === 'Geel Goud' ? 'yellow' : 'white' " for="{{ variation.id }}"> <span class="sr-only">{{ variation.title }}</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

(this code is then duplicated in my view for 'METAL CARAT')

This is then in my controller:

```
$scope.isSelected = function (obj) {
  $scope.$index = 1;

  var getObj = obj.target,
      getTitle = $(getObj).attr('ng-title'),
      getPrice = $(getObj).attr('ng-price');

  $scope.title = getTitle;
  $scope.price = getPrice;

  //console.log($(getObj).attr('ng-title'))
}

$scope.triggerClick = function () {
  $timeout(function() {
    $(':checked').trigger('click');
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing way unnecessary work on your input buttons, first off you should not use ng-model and ng-checked on the same element.

From angular docs:

> Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.

Also ng-init should almost never be used too:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

That being said why don' we simplify things a little bit:

```
<fieldset ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 main-label">
            <span class="result">{{selected.title}}</span> 
            <span class="price">({{ selected.price }})</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul>
                  <input type="radio" name='radio' ng-model='selected' ng-value='{title:"18ct",price:"0"}' />
                  <input type="radio" name='radio' ng-model='selected' ng-value='{title:"22ct",price:"+20"}' />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And in your controler:

```
angular.module("app", [])
    .controller("ctrl", ctrl);

ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.selected = {
        title: "Select",
        price: 0
    }
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNNQBp

And if you need arbitrary id for later uses just add it in ng-value as an object attribute.

I hope you can manage to figure out ng-classes by yourself.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Please be aware that the data is dynamic (API) so i am unable to use:

 $scope.selected = {
        title: "Select",
        price: 0
    }

Comment: It does not matter, the code in the controller is just a placeholder, and when you fetch the data, just assign it to a variable in controller, and then reference it via ng-value.

Comment: cant get it to work. wondering if its got something to do with my ng-repeat

Comment: had to use $parent on the model

Comment: Last question.. in your codepen can you default check the first radio button. I have been trying for ages and cant do it. I have even created a boolean within $scope.selected to make sure its selected

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqKGMm

Minor modification, you have to reference the object that is value, to the ng-model, and angular takes care of the rest. So after you fetch your data from the server you reference that object (first radio value) to the ng-model.

Comment: I hope you realize the difference between soft copy and hard copy in javascript. For strings and ints, by doing something like this = that, js creates another string/int in memory, but for objects, js simply references "that" object, and editing a param in "this" object actually edits "that" object.

Here is a codepen so you better understand:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqGXMP

That being said, when using a string or int in ng-value (ng-value not even needed here, value enough) , angular simply checks are two strings/ints equal, but with objects, angular checks is that the same object.